# Square button doesn't respond

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Today the square button on the Samsung Galaxy S6, the one used to close all apps running in the background, stopped responding. It was working perfectly fine one minute but stopped the nextime and now isn't working. I have tried restarting my phone but no luck. Is there anyway to fix this?